# How to eagerly load City From IdentityUser .Include Method not working

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a project Wedding Hall website in Asp.net MVC. I'm building API using Asp.net web API. For authentication and authorization I'm using Asp.net identity. I have learned something about navigation properties in class and I'm trying to load city class information The problem that I'm getting is I'm unable to load City using .Include Method. With the following code I'm getting null value in city field.

I've tried to use .Include method to eagerly load the city class but that method is not showing.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string CNIC { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }

    }
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext context;
        public UsersController()
        {
            context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetUsers()
        {
            return context.Users.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import System.Data.Entity namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

navigation property must defined as virtual:

```
 public virtual City City { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not working. The problem is with the obj of the ApplicationUser class(Users) that is inherited from IdentityUser that don't have the include method

Comment: Import this namespace using System.Data.Entity;